# where to place the db.close to close the mysql connection that inside of a function in python script

Tags: python

i have this psudo code  which i want to close the mysql connection after the for loop

but i am getting the below error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./myscript.py", line 201, in <module>
    db.close
    NameError: name 'db' is not defined
```

the code looks like the below:

```
    def get_content(id):
            db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='user',password='password',database='dcname')
            #get cursor
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select  id,num from table  where job_db_inx={0}".format(index))
            result = cursor.fetchall()

    for job in list
        id = get_content(id)
        print(id)


    db.close()
```

where should i place the db.close to close all the db connections

Comment: `db` is actually a connection and you should close it inside  `get_content(id)` where it was created.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a context manager here:

```
import contextlib

def get_content(id, cursor):
        cursor.execute("select  id,num from table  where job_db_inx={0}".format(index))
        result = cursor.fetchall()

with contextlib.closing(mysql.connector.connect(...)) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    for job in list
        id = get_content(id, cursor)
        print(id)
```

I used [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) here, but there's a very good chance that any given db api is already implemented as its own context manager. Python has a standard [`dbapi`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) that is worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

The actual code should look like: (make sure `conn` is closed)

```
def get_content(id,conn):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select  id,num from table  where job_db_inx={0}".format(id))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result

try:
  conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='user',password='password',database='dcname')
  for job in list
       id = get_content(id,conn)
        print(id)
finally:
   conn.close()
```

Comment: but since i am looping and getting the results  get_content() ,is it agood idea to open aclose for each iteration ?

Comment: Open the connection once and pass it to get_content. Make sure you close it.

Comment: but i need to get the data for every loop , can  you give me example of how doing that ?

Comment: Open the connection before the loop and pass it to the function get_content. is it clear?